Execute chunk periodically in Quarto
What I want is to generate a html document with quarto and execute a code chunk every 10 seconds. Is it possible? (In shiny I can get similar functionality by using reactivePoll package).
This is my attempt:
---
title: "Auotmatic refreshing"
format: html
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r}
# This is the chunk to re-execute
cat(Sys.time())
```

<script>
  // Function to reload the chunk every 10 seconds
  function refreshChunk() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.cell .output').forEach(el => el.remove());
    let rChunks = document.querySelectorAll('.cell_code.cell_r');
    rChunks.forEach(chunk => {
      let button = chunk.querySelector('button[aria-label="Run Cell"]');
      if (button) {
        button.click();
      }
    });
  }
  setInterval(refreshChunk, 10000);
</script>


Is using a Shiny runtime an option?
